Implementing live chat in a website using SignalR with ASP.NET Core and Angular 10
I'm currently working on integrating live chat functionality into our product website. The technology stack I'm using includes SignalR with ASP.NET Core on the backend and Angular 10 on the frontend.
In the implementation, I have two approaches in mind for sending messages from users to the admin:

Sending message to a single user using connection ID:
public async Task SendToUser(string user, string receiverConnectionId, string message, string imgurl)
{
    await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message, imgurl);  
}


Sending message to admin by creating dynamic group:
var roomname = user_admin;
await Clients.Group(roomname)
             .SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", userRoomConnection.User, message, DateTime.Now);



I'm torn between these two methods. On one hand, sending messages directly to a single user using their connection ID seems straightforward and efficient. On the other hand, creating a dynamic group for each new user to send messages to the admin might offer more flexibility and scalability.
Which approach would be better in terms of performance, scalability, and overall best practice? Are there any potential pitfalls or considerations I should be aware of with either approach?

I'm not sure if this helps your decision, but "groups" in signalR aren't quite as you'd expect most of the time. The information is only losely stored, and isn't persisted server side at all.  There's also no API to get group membership...etc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups
My preferred method, when we did an enterprise application (web and mobile) implementing SignalR (and allowed for scalability) - was to maintain our own connection collections, with qualifiers or discriminator fields.  When we needed to send to a group of users, we'd simply gather that list server side, using the discriminator, and then send the messages.
SignalR provides pretty nice methods to send to collections of connections.
If you scroll around and read through the above link, they are basically doing just that in the section "Storing groups in the database"

If we're sending messages to a group of users, it's a different scenario. I need to first implement chat between two users. In your opinion, it would be better to send messages directly to the user with a connection rather than creating a temporary group for every two users right?

See this link section for more help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#single-user-groups.

@rakshith So, the easiest way to make sure it all comes together later, is literally to do just what you're saying.  There are caveats that are going to come up, like local echo of what the user said (returning to the room), disconnects where you have to replay the observable to both or either user.   When you add them to a 'chat' between two users, it essentially is just as you say, a group of just two users, but I'd roll your own on the server to maintain it.  When we first implemented it, it was nothing more than a thread safe static class that held an list of an object to hold connections
